# how do i to run multiple java programs/classes from the command line at the same time (or is it not possible)?

Tags: java

I noticed that I could compile multiple java programs/classes from the command line at the same time.
 Here's how I did it (they have to be in the same folder/location):

1. open command prompt
2. locate file
3. type "javac filename1.java filename2.java filename3.java..."

Is it possible to run them at the same time too?
I've tried to do this multiple times, but it just doesn't seem to work. Either I get an error message, or the program fails to run.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: That is the command to compile multiple java files, are you getting an error? Or is it generating corresponding class files and you don't know what to do next?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Launch three separate applets at the same time? Why not just `javac app1` in one console, then `javac app2` in another, then `javac app3` in a third?

Comment: Command line on what? On *nix you should be able to run `java one.class; java two.class; etc` or you could do this in simultaneous shells.

Comment: @nerdwaller I think that would run them consecutively.  OP wants to run them at the same time.  On *nix, a better way would be `java one.class & java two.class &`

Comment: @emory - That's right, I was confusing the difference between `&&` and `;`, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @nerdwaller I know about `&`.  What is `&&`?

Comment: @emory - `&&` will execute the latter command only if the former had successfully completed.  Whereas `;` will execute sequentially regardless of exit status.  [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/619016/what-is-the-difference-between-command-command-and-command-command) gives some more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to run multiple java programs simultaneously.  One way is to create a java program like so

```
class Main{
     public static void main(String[]args){
          new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                       NameOfFirstJavaAppClass.main(fill,in,the,args);
               }
          }.start();
          new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                       NameOfSecondJavaAppClass.main(fill,in,the,args);
               }
          }.start();
     }
}
```